# Arranging data in access or macro

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have some data in the excel sheet and I am trying to get those data to Access. But the data is really in bad shape. This is the what the excel has.

**country, product, id, 1qtr 2010 flash, 2qtr 2010 flash, 3qtr 2010 flash, 4qtr 2010 flash, 
1qtr 2011 budget etc....**

Now as you can see this is a very bad way of storing data. I want to run some queries on this table but that's difficult with current schema because the new columns would be added each year.

I want some way (may be some sql queries) which will create a new table with these data in better structure, like below

**country, product, id, Value, Year, Qtr, Type**

Hope you got my point. Can anyone suggest me some ways either in Access or in Excel

Comment: Please explain how your data is split into rows and columns. Maybe all the data you've shown is in a single cell, but we cannot tell from your description.

Comment: ok one row may be...  US, laptop , o-123 , 100$, 200$ , 300 $....etc

Comment: SO as u can see its country, product, id , then the values based on the quarter of the year and type of value like budget or flash..

Comment: Why dont you start transfering your old format to the new one ?

Comment: I already have a bulk of data and the new excel I will be getting that will also be in old format...so i need some way that access takes the data and run some queries to convert the data to new format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general form of the solution you seek is to use a UNION query, something like this:

```sql
SELECT [country], [product], [id],
    [1qtr 2010 flash] AS [Value],
    2010 AS [Year],
    1 AS [Qtr],
    "flash" AS [Type]
FROM ImportedTable
UNION ALL
SELECT [country], [product], [id],
    [2qtr 2010 flash] AS [Value],
    2010 AS [Year],
    2 AS [Qtr],
    "flash" AS [Type]
FROM ImportedTable
UNION ALL
SELECT [country], [product], [id],
    [3qtr 2010 flash] AS [Value],
    2010 AS [Year],
    3 AS [Qtr],
    "flash" AS [Type]
FROM ImportedTable
...
```

You could save such a query with a name like [ReformatDataFromExcel], then when you import an updated Excel feed that has new columns you can update the query by copying and pasting new UNION ALL clauses as required.

--Edit--

Or, if you wanted to build up the SQL query strings via code then some VBA like this...

```vbs
Sub BuildQueries()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, fld As DAO.Field, sSQL As String
Dim sYear As String, sQtr As String, sType As String, a() As String
Set cdb = CurrentDb
For Each fld In cdb.TableDefs("ImportedTable").Fields
    Select Case fld.Name
        Case "country", "product", "id"
            ' do nothing
        Case Else
            a = Split(fld.Name, " ", -1, vbBinaryCompare)
            sQtr = Left(a(0), 1)
            sYear = a(1)
            sType = a(2)
            sSQL = _
                    "SELECT [country], [product], [id], " & _
                    "[" & fld.Name & "] AS [Value], " & _
                    sYear & " AS [Year], " & _
                    sQtr & " AS [Qtr], " & _
                    """" & sType & """ AS [Type] " & _
                    "FROM ImportedTable"
            Debug.Print sSQL  ' or whatever you want to do with the query
    End Select
Next
Set fld = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

...could build SQL strings like this:

```sql
SELECT [country], [product], [id], [1qtr 2010 flash] AS [Value], 2010 AS [Year], 1 AS [Qtr], "flash" AS [Type] FROM ImportedTable
SELECT [country], [product], [id], [2qtr 2010 flash] AS [Value], 2010 AS [Year], 2 AS [Qtr], "flash" AS [Type] FROM ImportedTable
SELECT [country], [product], [id], [3qtr 2010 flash] AS [Value], 2010 AS [Year], 3 AS [Qtr], "flash" AS [Type] FROM ImportedTable
SELECT [country], [product], [id], [4qtr 2010 flash] AS [Value], 2010 AS [Year], 4 AS [Qtr], "flash" AS [Type] FROM ImportedTable
SELECT [country], [product], [id], [1qtr 2011 budget] AS [Value], 2011 AS [Year], 1 AS [Qtr], "budget" AS [Type] FROM ImportedTable
SELECT [country], [product], [id], [2qtr 2011 budget] AS [Value], 2011 AS [Year], 2 AS [Qtr], "budget" AS [Type] FROM ImportedTable
SELECT [country], [product], [id], [3qtr 2011 budget] AS [Value], 2011 AS [Year], 3 AS [Qtr], "budget" AS [Type] FROM ImportedTable
SELECT [country], [product], [id], [4qtr 2011 budget] AS [Value], 2011 AS [Year], 4 AS [Qtr], "budget" AS [Type] FROM ImportedTable
```

Comment: Yes..I like the idea...Only problem is tables created as union cannot be exported back to excel as pivot table....but I can write 4-5 small queries which does the above and can be called one after another in a macro...

Comment: Is there a way for me to loop through the data and set the qtr, years etc dynamically based on some string manipulation?

Comment: @user2472382 Yes, you could do something like that. See update to this answer.

Comment: Nice..I am new to VBA...so did not know abt those features.. I wish there were a like button ...thanks a lot...

Comment: @user2472382 RE: "I wish there were a like button" - On Stack Overflow we can "upvote" a question or answer if we "like" it (and we can also "downvote" a question or answer if we "dislike" it). The voting buttons are the up/down triangles on the left-hand side at the top of each question and answer.